# MYSQL: select row where field is smaller than other

Tags: mysql

this is my mysql query in php:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE logins < limit")
```

the mysql_affected_rows() returns -1. why this simple query doesnt work? field and table names are correct i've double checked

Comment: "...check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit' at line 1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try quoting your column names with backticks:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE `logins` < `limit`")
```

You've got a column name same as a reserved MySQL keyword (`limit`).

Comment: You got it Nick! I was just cheeky enough to turn it into an answer. Half points to Nick Rulez!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `mysql_affected_rows` for `SELECT` queries, as per the PHP Manual:

> **mysql_affected_rows**
>
> Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query

Use `mysql_num_rows` instead.

Also, as p.campbell pointed out, don't forget to backquote the name of your 'limit' column, since you use a reserved work as the column name.